# What is the image of the empty category under a given functor?

Tags: category-theory, functors

I'm pretty sure this is obvious, but just making sure.
Does the empty category always map (via functor) to the empty subcategory of the codomain (category)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very poorly worded. It sounds like you're asking what the image of the functor $F:\varnothing\to C$ is, where $C$ is any category and $\varnothing$ is the empty category, with no objects and no morphisms. Is this correct?

If so, then there is exactly one such functor $F$ for every category $C$ (in other words, $\varnothing$ is the initial category). Its image is the empty category, regarded as a subcategory of $C$.

Comment: Correct.  Where is the ambiguity in question?

Comment: @user3146 "map to" sounds like you're talking about the image of an object or a morphism in the domain of a functor, which of course there are none of in this case, rather than the image of the entire domain. Many students have various confusions about empty domains and it is difficult to tell from your phrasing alone whether you're one of them.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks for trying to help, but I doubt that is what D. Brogan was talking about.  In both the title and body of my question I say mapping from a category to another category.  And, I specify a functor doing the mapping.  And, I specify the domain and codomain as categories, one of which being the empty one as you said, which also makes it clear (but is unnecessary to know because of the other reasons that I just listed) that that is not what I meant.

Comment: I'm only referring to the fact that it's hard to parse the meaning of the title of the question. I feel it's bad English, as stated now. The body of the question cleared it up for me. I would have written something akin to "What is the image of the empty category under a given functor?" You may agree or disagree. This is just my opinion.

Comment: @user3146 I don't see how any of that is a response to my point. Functors have domains with elements-or at least objects-which one often talks of being mapped to objects of the codomain. One rarely talks of (a subcategory of) the domain being mapped to some subcategory of the codomain, especially since images of categories under functors are not well behaved.

Comment: @D.Brogan Okay. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Sorry.  I didn't talk of a subcategory of the domain.  My title says "empty category as the domain."

Comment: @user3146 Yes, that's why I included the parentheses. A category is, of course, a subcategory of itself.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Well, for what it's worth, I think people do often speak of mapping a category to the subcategory of another.  That's what a diagram is, right?  And, thus same is true for diagonal functors, cones, limits, and so forth.

Comment: @user3146 Given a functor $F:C\to D,$ the image $F(C)$ of $F$ is not in general a subcategory of $D.$

Comment: @D.Brogan Right.  What's that in reference to?  My diagram comment?

Comment: You say "Well, for what it's worth, I think people do often speak of mapping a category to the subcategory of another." While I'm not offering counter evidence, I would expect it's not really true (except in special circumstances) for this reason.